R pagination API loop
When I approach the API I get the first 100 rows (the API is max 100 rows per page). So to get all the pages I create a while loop. This works fine but I get all the pages except the first page.
Ok, this is what I have so far:
# Required packages
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
library(keyring) 


url = "https://app.website.com/api/account/v1/account/sales/export/default-extended?       period_filter_on=updated_date&period=this_month"

request <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste(key_get(service = "Website"))))
this.raw.content <- rawToChar(request$content)
apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
next_url <- apiresponse$data$next_page_url
apidata <- apiresponse$data$data

data <- list()
i <- 1

while(!is.null(next_url)) {
  request <- GET(apiresponse$data$next_page_url,
             add_headers(Authorization = paste(key_get(service = "Website"))))
  this.raw.content <- rawToChar(request$content)
  apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
  next_url <- apiresponse$data$next_page_url
  temp <- apiresponse$data$data
  rownames(temp) <- NULL
  data[[i]] <- temp
  i <- i + 1
}


result <- do.call(rbind, data)

This code works, but when I look at "data <- list()", the list of the first page is missing.
When I look at "apidata <- apiresponse$data$data" then I see the results of the first page.
I have read several solutions, but I don't know how to solve this.

The first thing you do in your while loop is get the next page of data, so add the first page’s data to your list before starting the loop. Or, get the next page of data at the end of the loop rather than the start.

As @Limey mentioned, the first page never gets stored. Try :
url = "https://app.website.com/api/account/v1/account/sales/export/default-extended?       period_filter_on=updated_date&period=this_month"

request <- GET(url, add_headers(Authorization = paste(key_get(service = "Website"))))
this.raw.content <- rawToChar(request$content)
apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
next_url <- apiresponse$data$next_page_url
temp <- apiresponse$data$data
data <- list()
i <- 1
rownames(temp) <- NULL
data[[i]] <- temp

while(!is.null(next_url)) {
  i <- i + 1
  request <- GET(apiresponse$data$next_page_url,
             add_headers(Authorization = paste(key_get(service = "Website"))))
  this.raw.content <- rawToChar(request$content)
  apiresponse <- jsonlite::fromJSON(this.raw.content)
  next_url <- apiresponse$data$next_page_url
  temp <- apiresponse$data$data
  rownames(temp) <- NULL
  data[[i]] <- temp
}


ah great. Thanks for the help. I managed to solve it with that example.
